# Weird behavior of odbc::dbGetQuery against Oracle (SQL query is correct!)

Tags: sql, r, oracle, odbc

I don't get that.

In R, running such a query against Oracle, via a call to `odbc::dbGetQuery(con, query)`:

```
SELECT
    em_id,
    status,
    CASE
        WHEN bl_id IS NOT NULL AND fl_id IS NOT NULL
        THEN CONCAT(bl_id, fl_id)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS location
FROM em;
```

will return:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1752: HY000:
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

On the other hand, almost the same one:

```
SELECT
    em_id,
    CASE
        WHEN bl_id IS NOT NULL AND fl_id IS NOT NULL
        THEN CONCAT(bl_id, fl_id)
        ELSE NULL
    END,
    status
FROM em;
```

will succeed!?

What makes the first request fail?

- The `CASE` block just before the `FROM`, and
- The name given to it (`AS location`)

Only when both previous conditions are false does the query succeed...

Note that *both* queries are correctly run against an SQL Server DB...

What can I do to make those correct queries run without errors on both DB?

Comment: Simply `bl_id || fl_id`? (I.e. no case expression needed.)

Comment: You did not understand the problem. Your suggestion is to change the code, and make it work on Oracle only. Though, that's not the problem. The thing is both queries are syntactically correct, and both run without any errors in SQL Management Studio (for SQL Server) and in SQL Developer (for Oracle). Both do work. But, when run from an R script, via odbc::dbGetQuery, the first query does not work anymore against an Oracle DB.

Comment: Your suggestion of removing the case is not a good one, generally speaking, as this is only one example. But I do have hundreds (yes, really) of such queries which do work perfectly when run from SQL Developer, but don't anymore when run from the R script...

Comment: And it seems we may neither have a CASE expression as the last column, nor give it a name... if we want to run it from an R script.

Comment: Are those *exactly* what you run - or do you maybe have the semicolon at the end of the one that errors and not on the one that works?

Comment: The two queries seem to vary in only two ways: (1) the order of columns selected, and (2) the naming (or not) `as location`. Can you confirm which of those two changes are responsible for the different behavior, or does it take both differences to trigger the error?

Comment: I do confirm that the SQL queries are exactly like that -- no semicolon error... And, yes, any of those 2 things make the initial query fail... I can't name a CASE block, and I can't finish with a CASE block (named or not) as the last column.

Comment: Since the few guesses made here haven't solved the problem, it's not enough to 'confirm': you need to show the actual R code you are running and give details about driver and library and DB versions.  Also I would suggest using ROracle https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html when working with R; it's much more efficient.